# Trying to debug INNER JOIN cannundrum

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am using a smaller function to try and debug a bigger function's inner join. I am a novice who has little experience of using joins. In fact, I've only just started trying to use inner-joins two/three days ago as my first experience of joins. The smaller function is as follows:

```
$data3 = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $posted_email) . '\'';
echo "post email var dump:   ";
var_dump($posted_email);
$exam_recordation = mysql_query("SELECT Student_email FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE Student_email = $data3) AND Student_email <> $data3");
echo "<br>recordation query:   ";
echo "SELECT Student_email FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE Student_email = $data3) AND Student_email <> $data3";
echo "<br>recordation var dump:   ";
var_dump($exam_recordation);
echo "<table border=='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";
while ($fetch_record = mysql_fetch_array($exam_recordation))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $fetch_record['Student_email'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
//inner join should use the email of the partner out of $exam query to find their name and print it
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email = $exam_recordation[Student_email]");
echo "<br><br>INNER JOIN query:   ";
echo "SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email = $exam_recordation[Student_email]";

echo "<br>query result dump:   ";
var_dump($name_query);
```

The result of all that is as follows:

```
post email var dump:
array
  'Student_email' => string 'nuts@prof.com' (length=13)

recordation query: SELECT Student_email FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE Student_email = 'nuts@prof.com') AND Student_email <> 'nuts@prof.com'
recordation var dump:
resource(6, mysql result)
Name
foiling@gorilla.com


INNER JOIN query: SELECT DISTINCT student.name FROM student INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email WHERE student.email = 
query result dump:
boolean false
```

Where is the problem you ask? In the INNER JOIN I cannot figure out why it does not take the email from the $exam_recordation query into it even though it is picked up in the table. In the bigger function, I would have the INNER JOIN working with recordation query in a while loop to produce what I hope is the desired effects. I've been struggling with this problem for a while and since my attempts to fix/ask for help to fix the main function as a whole have failed, I thought I'd try just the INNER JOIN for this question as it seems to be the main culprit for the head banging against brick walls.

Answer (score 0):

```
$exam_recordation = mysql_query("SELECT Student_email FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE Student_email = $data3) AND Student_email <> $data3");
echo "<br>recordation query:   ";
echo "SELECT Student_email FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE Student_email = $data3) AND Student_email <> $data3";
echo "<br>recordation var dump:   ";
var_dump($exam_recordation);
echo "<table border=='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";
while ($fetch_record = mysql_fetch_array($exam_recordation))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $fetch_record['Student_email'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

---

```
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email = $exam_recordation[Student_email]");
```

See here, you are fetching the query with variable $fetch_record, but later you are using the $exam_recordation, which is only mysql query resource, but not fetched data.

Comment: So I should be using $fetch_record[Student_email] instead of $exam_recordation[Student_email] in the INNER JOIN query? I've just tried that and it hasn't changed the result. I originally thought mysql_query executes it to the point where it stores it in the $exam_recordation variable which would make it accessible when called upon in my INNER JOIN the way I have it in my answer.

Comment: It stores it, but as resource. See the documentation for resource - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php . In your case I would suggest `while($fetch_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($exam_recordation)) { $email = $fetch_record['Student_email']; }` And then in INNER JOIN: `WHERE student.email = $email`

Comment: Right, so that got the email into the INNER JOIN how ever I'm still getting a false boolean for the INNER JOIN query dump. I have worked out it is because $email returns the email without single quotes which it requires. My first thought is to implode them in and then use the resulting variable in place of $email. Something along the lines of : `while ($fetch_record = mysql_fetch_array($exam_recordation))
 {
  $email = $fetch_record['Student_email'];
  $data8 = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $email) . '\'';
 }` Just tried this and I'm getting an implode error however it worked for $posted_email.

Comment: Just surround it by single quotes -> `WHERE student.email = '$email'`. However, the whole thing with putting variables in the query and the whole using of mysql_* functions is going not so slowly to the past and considered wrong and vulnerable when interacts with the users. Once you get the idea of PHP<->SQL, you should switch to a new library like MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Ok, well thatnks for the all the help. I've heard of MySQLi and seen PDO around stackoverflow questions but not really looked into them that much. Now time to try and take the fix from here into the main function and see if I can get it all working.